# Poblemas con el inicio de sesion con php

Tags: php, login

Hola mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo este código en el cual hay un contador que debe de incrementarse si después de hacer el recorrido por la base de datos encuentra el mismo valor ingresado en este caso el usuario, el tema es que antes me funcionaba pero ahora no y no se por que pues al no tener un incremento no va a la página de `contenido.php` sino a la otra, y los datos ingresados tanto usuario como contraseña esta correctos en la base.

```
<?php

try{

    $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));

    $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));

    $contador=0;

    $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=gesyagro" , "alejo", "15898920");

    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


    $sql="SELECT * FROM documentacion_usuario WHERE DocUsuario= :login";

    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);    

    $resultado->execute(array(":login"=>$login));

        while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){           

            /*echo "Usuario: " . $registro['DocUsuario'] . " Contraseña: " . $registro['DocContrasena'] . "<br>";   
        }*/
            if (password_verify($password, $registro['DocContrasena'])) 
            {
                        $contador++;
            }       

        }

        if ($contador>0) {

            header("location: contenido.php");

            }else{

            header("location: Registro.html");
            }

        $resultado->closeCursor();
        }catch(Exception $e){

    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: no veo para qué usar `htmlentities` ni `addslashes`. Si tu intención es sanitizar la variable para evitar una inyección SQL, PDO de por sí sanitiza la variable en el execute, aunque yo optaría por hacer un `$resultado->bindValue` antes y llamar al execute sin argumentos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo me dice que entre `htmlentities` y `addslashes` el string `$password` no es lo que tu quieres que sea; intenta lo siguiente:

```
try{

 $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
 $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
 $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=gesyagro" , "alejo", "15898920");

 $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

 $resultado=$base->prepare("SELECT * FROM documentacion_usuario WHERE DocUsuario= :login");    
 $resultado->execute(array(":login"=>$login));

 while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){           

    if (password_verify($password, $registro['DocContrasena'])){
      header("location: contenido.php");

    } else {
      throw new Exception('Verificación: ' . var_export(password_verify($password, $registro['DocContrasena']). true) , '<br />Usuario: ' .  $registro['DocUsuario'] . '<br />Contraseña DB: ' . var_export($registro['DocContrasena'], true) . '<br />Contraseña POST: ' . var_export($password, true)  );

      header("location: Registro.html");
    }
}

$resultado->closeCursor();
}catch(Exception $e){
  die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

La verdad será revelada en el mensaje de la excepción.

Puedes sanitizar tu input usando las funciones [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) y [filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input-array.php) que justamente están diseñadas para ello en lugar de esas dos funciones que pueden modificar tu string.

Comment: Hola, trate de implementarlo como tu me dijiste pero me saca error, y el tema es que en vez de acceder al contenido se va a la página de registro.

Comment: Puedes quitar el header para ver el mensaje de error antes de que seas redirigido

Comment: Hola, ya encontre el problema, era que en la BBDD tenia el campo de contraseña como varchar 50 y al estar enciptada claramente no iba a entrar asi que la puse de 255 y funciono todo, ahora esoy haciendo la sesion con session_start() y la variable $_SESSION